# Can't convert RGB to UIColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm trying to convert a rgb color to a UIColor by using a function i've found, but it cant seem to give me the right color. Why am i getting an completely wrong color from the one in photoshop?

Here is an illustration:

[image]

The color from the photoshop file is the following: 009d13

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColorFromRGB(009e13)
```

## Function

```
func UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: UInt) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
```

Comment: dont u know that there is Apple RGB?
there will be a slight change in opacity compared to photoshop RGB and apple RGB. when doing work in photoshop change the color scheme to apple RGB

Comment: Perhaps this is a little endian problem?

Comment: Shouldn't you call the function with a *hex constant*: `0x009e13` ?

Comment: Turn off 'translucency' in your `UINavigationBar`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the hex value you're using? I'd like to replicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have hex code of a colour then best way is to use uicolor + hex lib.
https://github.com/kevinrenskers/UIColor-HexString

For swift

https://github.com/yeahdongcn/UIColor-Hex-Swift